# What are 'default' props in xinput/libinput for?

Tags: linux, touchpad, xinput, libinput

I wanted to adjust vertical (two-finger) scrolling speed via `xinput` because my DE's settings utility does not expose that setting. So, I ran `xinput --list-props` to fetch a list of available settings for my touchpad. I noticed that many properties have 2 versions of itself: 1 with default and one without:

```
Device '******* Touchpad':
Device Enabled (201):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (203): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (349): 1
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (350): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (351):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (352):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (353):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (354):   0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (355):  1, 0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (356):  1, 0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (328):   1
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (329):   0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (357):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (358):    1
libinput Scroll Methods Available (330):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (331):   1, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (332):   1, 0, 0
libinput Click Methods Available (359): 1, 1
libinput Click Method Enabled (360):    1, 0
libinput Click Method Enabled Default (361):    1, 0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (362):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (363):    0
libinput Accel Speed (337): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (338): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (339):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (340):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (341):   1, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (342): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (343): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (313): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (314):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (315):    0, 0
Device Node (316):  "/dev/input/event16"
Device Product ID (317):    1267, 12491
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (344):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (345):   1
libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (346):    30
libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (347):    15
libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (348):    1
```

Do the default ones persist after restart and populate their non-default counterparts as the name suggests?

I looked at `https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinput` and man pages for xinput but didn't notice the answer to my question.